# Change group after a mailing is scheduled results in mailing still being send to the original members

Tags: civimail, groups, smartgroups

When we *schedule a mailing* in civimail we use a normal group (not a smart group) as the target audience for this mailing. Prior to 4.6.2 (we think), we could change the group before the mailing was send (even though it was scheduled) and the changes to the group would be taken into account when the actual sending of the mail occurred.

We are now on version 4.6.4 and looked into the database a bit to see what happens when somebody schedules a mailing. It seems as the schedule button fills the "*civicrm_mailing_recipients*" table and this table is used when the mailing actually starts. So adding a contact to the group(s) you used does nothing.

Is this behavior correct/by design? And is there a workaround to get the latest group members when the mailing actually starts?

Comment: We added a pull request to the civi crm git with a fix for this issue: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6087

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [CiviMail and Smart Groups: when does CiviCRM identify the actual list of email recipients?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/593/civimail-and-smart-groups-when-does-civicrm-identify-the-actual-list-of-email-r).  I don't think your fix is likely to be accepted upstream for the reasons Lobo provided on that ticket.  That doesn't mean you can't use this fix if it works for you, of course, just that it can't be merged into the upstream code.