# Dynamically send scheduled email to a group?

Tags: civimail

I'd like to schedule an email to be sent next month to a group.

Is there a way for me to schedule the email today, but to still have individuals that are added next week to the group receive that email?

Civicrm 4.6.4 and Drupal 7.38

Comment: Please [edit](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/4372/edit) your question to include the version of CiviCRM you are on and also your CMS and version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this, but [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/593/civimail-and-smart-groups-when-does-civicrm-identify-the-actual-list-of-email-r?rq=1) confirms that email recipients are defined at time of scheduling the mailing for smart groups.

(Since this is true for smart groups, I'm assuming this is also true for normal groups – indeed as my brief testing (above) demonstrates.)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified this but you should be able to create your email in civimail and schedule it to send to the group with the send date set for the date next month. It should send to all in the group on that date.

You could test it by setting up a test group and putting a test person in the group setting up the email to run in 15 minutes and then go and add another test person to the group and see if it sends to both contacts in the group.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it only sent to the contacts in the group at the time of scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

Another option will be to use a Smart Group with the search criteria set on the Group you want to target.

See [Smart Groups](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/smart-groups/) for details on how to set it up.

Comment: Thank you; I tried this, but even using a Smart Group with the search criteria set on the group I want to target returns the same results – namely, only the group members in the group at the time of the scheduling receive the email.

Comment: Just saw the same post. As a workaround solution, if the recipients join themselves the group through a form (ie opt-in) you could record an activity (as you are on drupal that's easy to accomplish with Webforms) when the form is submitted and use scheduled reminders based on that activity.

Answer (score 1):

If current and future members of the group have something in common relating to events, contributions, membership or activities then you may be able to create a scheduled reminder based on that common "something" and use
**Recipient(s)** - **Limit to** - **Select a group** to send to all members of your smart group at the time the email is sent.

I have never actually set up a scheduled reminder to run on a fixed date, but I know that mail recipients are determined at the time of sending the email for relative date sending.